# References for regularity of solution to fourth order elliptic/parabolic PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, parabolic-pde

After searching, all I could find was regularity of solutions to second-order PDEs like in *Partial Differential Equations* by *Evans* and *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations* by *Brezis*. A weak solution $u$ is found in $H^1_0$ then with improved regularity on the data, they can prove that $u \in H^2$.

I was wondering if there is anything similar for fourth-order equations, i.e. you prove a solution in $H^2 \cap H^1_0$ and then show that it is in $H^4$ for example.

This probably can work if we take a simple biharmonic equation. For sufficiently nice $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$
\begin{align*}
& \Delta^2 u = f, \ \ \ \text{ in }  \Omega \\
& u =0, \ \ \ \Delta u =0 \ \ \ \text{ on } \Omega
\end{align*}
We can show that $u \in H^2 \cap H^1_0$, then we take $z= \Delta u$ so now we have $\Delta z = f$ and we apply regularity theorem on $z$ to get that $z \in H^2 \cap H^1_0$ and thus $u \in H^4 \cap H^1_0$.

But what about abstract (general) fourth-order equations where we also have coefficients?
Are there any analogues theorems for fourth-order PDEs? Can you recommend books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theory of general elliptic and parabolic equations of arbitrary order with general boundary conditions (subject to certain quite general compatibility conditions) is indeed well-developed.  I would suggest the following texts.

- *Partial Differential Equations* by Wloka.  This treats both elliptic and parabolic problems with thorough detail.
- *Non-homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications* by Lions and Magenes.  Volume 1 handles elliptic theory, and Volume 2 handles parabolic problems.
- *Interpolation Theory, Function Spaces, Differential Operators* by Triebel.  Chapter 5 has a very general treatment of the elliptic theory you're after.
- *Sobolev Spaces, Their Generalizations, and Elliptic Problems in Smooth and Lipschitz Domains* by Agranovich.  This is limited to elliptic problems.
- *Elliptic Boundary Value Problems in Domains with Point Singularities* by Kozlov, Maz'ya, and Rossman.  The first part of the book actually deals with smooth boundaries, but then the latter part develops the theory in domains with worse boundary geometry.